# Nexus 5020 default route

Tags: routing, cisco-nexus-5k

I just setup a nexus 5020 and while I know it's primary purpose is to be used as an L2 device, according to docs, I should still be able to set a default route in the global routing table.  However, it does not seem to be working.

My setup is as follows:

```
Nexus 5020 <---> Core L3 device
```

I could not use the mgmt0 interface on the 5020 and have to set the mgmt ip on a vlan.  I have the ports trunked between the 5020 and the core l3 device.  I configured a default route on the 5020 however I am not able to ping out from the nexus nor reach the ip configured on the mgmt vlan from the outside world.

Any thoughts as to what I may be missing?

Comment: So, apparently we can enable a vlan for in-band management using the "management" command however after applying this to the vlan, I still have no connectivity. :(

Comment: You said you "could not use the management interface" - what do you mean? Is the management interface already in use? What's the reason for the secondary in-band management?

Comment: try "feature interface-vlan" to enable SVI (so say my Google-Fu)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

the management interface is in its own vrf, so in fact it can have 2 default routes one for the management adapter (vrf management) and if you enable SVIs you can put a default route in the default context. Also you have to ping from the box in the management context.

vrf context management
  ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.2.1.1

interface mgmt0
  ip address 10.2.7.50/16

ping 10.2.1.1 vrf management

See this
https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/344177

Answer (score 0):

To setup management ip
1. OOB management ip which is mgmt 0 interfaces it has its own vrf Management , an under this vrf you need to define route to reach gateway which is defined in your Layer 3 device.
2. Inband management all other interfaces comes under it VRF DEFAULT and you can define similar route for the gateway